# Android simple SQLite database application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I downloaded a simple login page code in zip file from
http://bit.ly/saket_github_loginpage.

Please check this application and tell me where the database file is. And how can I see this? I also want to create some new tables. How can I do this? I have tried getting it to work with the following code:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "saket.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String SAKET_TABLE_NAME = "login";
    public static final String SAKET_TABLE_NAME1 = "Employee";

    private static final String SAKET_TABLE_CREATE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + SAKET_TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
    "username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NO TNULL);";

    private static final String SAKET_TABLE_CREATE1 =
    "CREATE TABLE " + SAKET_TABLE_NAME1 + "(" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
    "name TEXT NOT NULL, Address TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private static final String SAKET_DB_ADMIN = "INSERT INTO" + 
    SAKET_TABLE_NAME+"values(1, admin, password, admin@gmail.com);";

    private static final String SAKET_DB_ADMIN1 = "INSERT INTO " + 
    SAKET_TABLE_NAME+"values(2, emp, password, Emp@gmail.com);";

    private static final String SAKET_DB_ADMIN2 = "INSERT INTO " +
    SAKET_TABLE_NAME1 + "values(1, mahesh, address, mahesh@gmail.com);";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        System.out.println("In constructor");   
   }
}
```

Comment: how to chk database in sqlite browser or sqlite manager...????

Comment: plz give fast answer as possible as u can..

Comment: I think you should look over your question after reading http://stackoverflow.com/faq. It might improve your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: i am new programer in android..@bvd So help me..

Comment: Any other hav the answer of my question....then plz ans...

Answer (score 0):

It's better you check on emulator, or a rooted device....... Follow these steps

1. In emulator run your application.
2. In eclipse go to Window>Show view>Other...>Android and click file explorer
3. In File explorer find a folder called data which should not be on your SD card
4. in data>data>your.application.packagename you can find database folder, your database is there
5. Find an icon called pull a file from device...... you can copy that database anywhere you like using this button....
6. There are many clients to view and operate the SQLITE database including firefox has one..... I recommend to use this.... If you are on ubuntu they have a good application in their software center..... [I don't remember the name so apologies for that]

I hope this works for you....

Comment: thanks for answering..but there is no data folder in android..so what i do now...???plz hep me..

Comment: Are you checking it in device???? You must have rooted device in that case, otherwise better check in emulator.......... 2. you have to check this data folder in eclipse not in device

Comment: in devices view of eclipse select that emulator, than open File Explorer view from eclipse, I have shown path on my answer, the first folder must be data...... in that folder search a subfolder called data

Comment: Window>Show view>Other...>Android find it there

Comment: Hi I hav One more Question ??

Comment: I want to transfer Microsoft Access Database tables in Sqlite database ,is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

1)You can see your database in file explorer. you can refer to file explorer as

Window -> show view -> other -> Select File Explorer.

in File Explorer goto

data -> data -> com.YourApplicationPackage -> YourDatabase

2)To create new table is by SQL  use `CREATE` query having stored in String Constant and the execute it by your SQLite database object. if your sqlite database object is db then it would be `db.execSQL(StringConstant);` String constant carries your SQL CREATE query...

I hope you got your answer....